# rake routes command is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, routes

I have run this rake routes command in terminal but not working, But it's working few days back. Please check it

```
jaskaran@jaskaran-Vostro-1550:~/rails_project$ rake routes
rake aborted!
Gem::LoadError: You have already activated rake 10.3.2, but your Gemfile requires rake 10.2.2. Prepending `bundle exec` to your command may solve this.
/home/jaskaran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:34:in `block in setup'
/home/jaskaran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:19:in `setup'
/home/jaskaran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `setup'
/home/jaskaran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/setup.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/jaskaran/rails_project/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/jaskaran/rails_project/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/jaskaran/rails_project/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- bundler/setup
/home/jaskaran/rails_project/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/jaskaran/rails_project/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/jaskaran/rails_project/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: Try giving `bundle exec rake routes` as the error says

Comment: 1 more query How can write down this routes in my routes file? edit_user GET           /users/:id/edit(.:format)      users#edit

Comment: You can just give `resources :users` i guess.

Comment: I have all ready define resources : users

Comment: Routing Error
No route matches [GET] "/edit_user/1"

Comment: Try posting it as another question explainaing your problem.

Comment: and this is my function>> def edit  @user = User.find(params[:id])   end

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55282/discussion-between-jaskaran-and-pavan).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try running `bundle exec rake routes` to ensure the proper version of Rake gets loaded.

Answer (score 3):

You need to update your gems to the latest available versions: `bundle update`

Comment: "bundle update" worked for me. After doing that, I could run "rake routes" without a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Rake versions seems to be different. So, run it as `bundle exec rake routes`. It should be working.

Answer (score 1):

The correct solution to your problem is to use `bundle exec`, as suggested by others, to load the version of Rake which your app expects. You may also wish to avoid needing to always run Rake commands with `bundle exec`. You can either

1) [Recommended] Update your app to use the same version of rake as you have running globally (10.3.2, which is the latest version)

or

2) [Not really recommended] Uninstall version 10.3.2 (actually, any version greater than the one you want) from your global gems and install version 10.2.2 (which your app is currently using)

```
rvm @global do gem uninstall rake
rvm @global do gem install rake --version 10.2.2
```

See [RVM documentation for global gemsets](http://rvm.io/gemsets/global)